# Uncaught OAuthException: (#3) Subject must be on whitelist

Tags: facebook, whitelist, subject

I am attempting to post a poll / question to a page's timeline and am getting the following fatal exception:

Uncaught OAuthException: (#3) Subject must be on whitelist

Google reveals no hits on that phrase whatsoever.  There are hits for "App must be on whitelist".  I notice that (for me at least), manually creating a question is no longer an option under "Offer, Event +".  Are questions now a deprecated feature on Facebook pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook mentioned its intent to deprecate the Questions feature in the past, and its most recent update on the issue seems to signal that this effort is well under way. In my own tests, the Questions feature is already disabled on most (but not quite all) Pages, and will return the '(#3) Subject must be on whitelist' error when this is the case.

http://newsroom.fb.com/News/620/An-Update-on-Facebook-Ads

Comment: Thanks for checking into that @ozmo -- I had searched Facebook for this news but came up blank.  It's a bit of a shame that FB is deprecating this feature as a poll with discrete options has applications beyond simply asking a question and gleaning answers from comments.